# C# file upload not supported type

Tags: c#, reactjs, wcf, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file from react front end to c# wcf back end. The file is being received in the service correctly but when it has been saved it is not opening in any program. Windows image viewer saying the file format is not supported.

the code in the back end is

```
string FilePath = Path.Combine
               (HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images"), fileName);

            int length = 0;
            using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                int readCount;
                var buffer = new byte[8192];
                while ((readCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    length += readCount;
                }
            }
```

the react front end is

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {

  const [myfile, setFile] = useState()

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  }

  const handleClick = () => {

    let file = myfile;

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Image',file,file.name);
    formData.append('ImageCaption','Testfile');

    axios({
      url: 'http://localhost:48526/Service1.svc/UploadFile?fileName=' + file.name,
      method: 'POST',
      data: formData
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  } 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="">
        <label>Select file</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}></input>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Uplaod</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obbyW.png)

[image: after upload]

[image: in image viewer]

Comment: Can you post the whole error message?

Comment: What is the type of `stream`? Is there a reason you aren't using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netcore-3.1 (to avoid your byte array etc)?

Comment: @mjwills file is there and it is saving the saving to the destination folder but somehow it is chaning the type of file. Same no of bytes and same name and extension is being saved but when you try to access the file window gives error of type not supported

Comment: Please attach to your question an example of a file you tried to upload, and the resulting file that your C# code wrote to the file system (so we can compare).

Comment: Please share a [mcve], including where `stream` comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you submitted the entire form directly to the WCF service and saved the entire form as an image.So you need to parse it after the WCF service gets the stream.

Here is my demo:

```
 [ServiceContract]
 [CustContractBehavior]
    public interface IReceiveData
    {
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{fileName}")]
        void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents);
    }
    public class RawDataService : IReceiveData
    {
        public void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents)
        {

            AntsCode.Util.MultipartParser parser = new AntsCode.Util.MultipartParser(fileContents);


            if (parser.Success)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test.png", parser.FileContents);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error");
            }



        }
    }
```

I used MultipartParser to parse the stream.For information about multipartparser,please refer to the following link:

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=multipartparser

You can also directly add the following classes to your project:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace AntsCode.Util
{
    public class MultipartParser
    {
        public MultipartParser(Stream stream)
        {
            this.Parse(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        public MultipartParser(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
        {
            this.Parse(stream, encoding);
        }

        private void Parse(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
        {
            this.Success = false;

            // Read the stream into a byte array
            byte[] data = ToByteArray(stream);

            // Copy to a string for header parsing
            string content = encoding.GetString(data);

            // The first line should contain the delimiter
            int delimiterEndIndex = content.IndexOf("\r\n");

            if (delimiterEndIndex > -1)
            {
                string delimiter = content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("\r\n"));

                // Look for Content-Type
                Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<=Content\-Type:)(.*?)(?=\r\n\r\n)");
                Match contentTypeMatch = re.Match(content);

                // Look for filename
                re = new Regex(@"(?<=filename\=\"")(.*?)(?=\"")");
                Match filenameMatch = re.Match(content);

                // Did we find the required values?
                if (contentTypeMatch.Success && filenameMatch.Success)
                {
                    // Set properties
                    this.ContentType = contentTypeMatch.Value.Trim();
                    this.Filename = filenameMatch.Value.Trim();

                    // Get the start & end indexes of the file contents
                    int startIndex = contentTypeMatch.Index + contentTypeMatch.Length + "\r\n\r\n".Length;

                    byte[] delimiterBytes = encoding.GetBytes("\r\n" + delimiter);
                    int endIndex = IndexOf(data, delimiterBytes, startIndex);

                    int contentLength = endIndex - startIndex;

                    // Extract the file contents from the byte array
                    byte[] fileData = new byte[contentLength];

                    Buffer.BlockCopy(data, startIndex, fileData, 0, contentLength);

                    this.FileContents = fileData;
                    this.Success = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private int IndexOf(byte[] searchWithin, byte[] serachFor, int startIndex)
        {
            int index = 0;
            int startPos = Array.IndexOf(searchWithin, serachFor[0], startIndex);

            if (startPos != -1)
            {
                while ((startPos + index) < searchWithin.Length)
                {
                    if (searchWithin[startPos + index] == serachFor[index])
                    {
                        index++;
                        if (index == serachFor.Length)
                        {
                            return startPos;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        startPos = Array.IndexOf<byte>(searchWithin, serachFor[0], startPos + index);
                        if (startPos == -1)
                        {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        index = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }

        private byte[] ToByteArray(Stream stream)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read <= 0)
                        return ms.ToArray();
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
        }

        public bool Success
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string ContentType
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string Filename
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public byte[] FileContents
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }
   
}
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

**UPDATE**

This is my project directory, it is a console project:

[image]

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using AntsCode.Util;
namespace ConsoleApp58
{
    public class ServerMessageLogger : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return null;
        }
        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
            ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CustContractBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior, IContractBehaviorAttribute
    {
        public Type TargetContract => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
            dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new ServerMessageLogger());
        }

        public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    [CustContractBehavior]
    public interface IReceiveData
    {
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{fileName}")]
        void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents);
    }
    public class RawDataService : IReceiveData
    {
        public void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents)
        {

            AntsCode.Util.MultipartParser parser = new AntsCode.Util.MultipartParser(fileContents);


            if (parser.Success)
            {

                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test.png", parser.FileContents);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error");
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(RawDataService), new Uri(baseAddress));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IReceiveData), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior() { HelpEnabled = true });
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Host opened");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**MultipartParser**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace AntsCode.Util
{
    public class MultipartParser
    {
        public MultipartParser(Stream stream)
        {
            this.Parse(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        public MultipartParser(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
        {
            this.Parse(stream, encoding);
        }

        private void Parse(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
        {
            this.Success = false;

            // Read the stream into a byte array
            byte[] data = ToByteArray(stream);

            // Copy to a string for header parsing
            string content = encoding.GetString(data);

            // The first line should contain the delimiter
            int delimiterEndIndex = content.IndexOf("\r\n");

            if (delimiterEndIndex > -1)
            {
                string delimiter = content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("\r\n"));

                // Look for Content-Type
                Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<=Content\-Type:)(.*?)(?=\r\n\r\n)");
                Match contentTypeMatch = re.Match(content);

                // Look for filename
                re = new Regex(@"(?<=filename\=\"")(.*?)(?=\"")");
                Match filenameMatch = re.Match(content);

                // Did we find the required values?
                if (contentTypeMatch.Success && filenameMatch.Success)
                {
                    // Set properties
                    this.ContentType = contentTypeMatch.Value.Trim();
                    this.Filename = filenameMatch.Value.Trim();

                    // Get the start & end indexes of the file contents
                    int startIndex = contentTypeMatch.Index + contentTypeMatch.Length + "\r\n\r\n".Length;

                    byte[] delimiterBytes = encoding.GetBytes("\r\n" + delimiter);
                    int endIndex = IndexOf(data, delimiterBytes, startIndex);

                    int contentLength = endIndex - startIndex;

                    // Extract the file contents from the byte array
                    byte[] fileData = new byte[contentLength];

                    Buffer.BlockCopy(data, startIndex, fileData, 0, contentLength);

                    this.FileContents = fileData;
                    this.Success = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private int IndexOf(byte[] searchWithin, byte[] serachFor, int startIndex)
        {
            int index = 0;
            int startPos = Array.IndexOf(searchWithin, serachFor[0], startIndex);

            if (startPos != -1)
            {
                while ((startPos + index) < searchWithin.Length)
                {
                    if (searchWithin[startPos + index] == serachFor[index])
                    {
                        index++;
                        if (index == serachFor.Length)
                        {
                            return startPos;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        startPos = Array.IndexOf<byte>(searchWithin, serachFor[0], startPos + index);
                        if (startPos == -1)
                        {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        index = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }

        private byte[] ToByteArray(Stream stream)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read <= 0)
                        return ms.ToArray();
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
        }

        public bool Success
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string ContentType
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string Filename
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public byte[] FileContents
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Try to transfer the image below:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. I was trying your solution it was giving the permission not granted error on the directory. I tried to change it with                 System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), parser.FileContents); but still an error of path not found is showing. Please guide how to solve it. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I can’t reproduce your problem, I suggest you try to save the picture to C drive using System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test.png", parser.FileContents) first, and then run it as an administrator. It can run on my computer.

Comment: I will provide my project, you can try to create it for testing.

Comment: The default data size transmitted by WCF is 64KB. If the picture exceeds 64KB, an error will be reported.

Comment: So the image to be transferred must be less than 64KB.

Comment: adding filename and the end of the path did the trick. Its working now. Thanks. System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Image/" + filename)

Comment: How I can add another parameter in multiparser? Thanks